# The effect of salt, pH and temperature to the salivary amylase

Tags: biochemistry

If I prepare the following set of tests, incubate for 15 mins, then add 2-3 drops of iodine solution to each test tube:
Salt test (1ml starch solution + 0.5 ml enzyme + 1ml 1M NaCl, incubate at 37 oC
Acid test (1ml starch solution + 0.5ml enzyme + 1ml 0.5HCl), at 37oC
Alkaline test (1ml starch solution + 0.5ml enzyme + 1ml 0.5M NaOH), at 37oC
Temp test (1ml starch solution + 0.5ml enzyme + 1ml H2O), place in water-bath
(75oC)

What is the effect of salt, pH and temperature to the salivary amylase? I don't know what exactly how salt effect.
high temperature will denature the enzyme.

How about salt?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me. **Homework questions** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). "*Homework*" is interpreted to mean any academic or other assignment, test preparation, or task given in relation to a class, educational setting, or self-learning.

Comment: At extreme pH (too acidic or too alkaline), the salivary amylase will be denatured.

At salt, the addition of salt will affect osmolarity and hinder the reaction.